# How to remove the last element in a list using scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have a requirement to return the last negative number in a list, using a recursive procedure.  Right now I have a recursive procedure that returns all negative numbers in the list.

```
(define returnLastNeg
  (lambda (lst) 
    (if (null? lst) 
        '() 
        (if (positive? (car lst)) 
            (returnLastNeg (cdr lst))
            (cons (car lst) (returnLastNeg (cdr lst)))))))
```

calling it with `(returnLastNeg'(1 -2 -3 4 -5 6))` returns

**Output:**

```
'(-2 -3 -5)
```

I need it to only return `-5` though.  I tried to modify my procedure to check to see if the last element in the list is positive.  If it is, I want to remove the last element and then call the procedure again.  But when I do that I get an error (below)

Modified procedure:

```
(define returnLastNeg-modified
  (lambda (lst) 
    (if (null? lst) 
        '() 
        (if (positive? (last lst))
            (remove (last lst) (lst))
            (cons (car lst) (returnLastNeg-modified (cdr lst)))))))
```

**ERROR:**

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(1 -2 -3 4 -5 6)
  arguments...: [none]
>
```

Comment: Given that you appear to be using Racket, you could always just use [`drop-right`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._drop-right%29%29) from `racket/list`.

Comment: @AlexisKing that gives me the same error

Comment: If `lst` is a list so that `(last lst)` works how it's a paradox that you also have `(lst)` in your code other places than the parameter list which clearly seems to try to run `lst` as if it evaluated to a procedure. `lst` cannot be both a procedure and a list so one of them will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach would be with a helper procedure (called "sub") in this example:

```scm
(define returnLastNeg
  (lambda (lst)
    (define sub
      (lambda (lst last-neg)
        (if (null? lst)
            last-neg
            (let ((c (car lst)))
              (sub (cdr lst)
                   (if (negative? c) c last-neg))))))  
    (sub lst null)))
```

**EDIT**

Knowing that

```scm
(define <procedureName> (lambda (<params>) ... )
```

is the same as

```scm
(define (<procedureName> <params>) ... )
```

and reformatting a little, this becomes:

```scm
(define (returnLastNeg lst)

  (define (sub lst last-neg)
    (if (null? lst)
        last-neg
        (let ((c (car lst)))
          (sub (cdr lst) (if (negative? c) c last-neg)))))

  (sub lst null))
```

I hope it's clearer

- `last-neg` gets set to `null` by the very last expression
- the recursive call to `sub` has 2 parameters (split on 2 lines in the initial version, but newlines don't matter).

This is the same as the even shorter version

```scm
(define (returnLastNeg lst)
  (let sub ((lst lst) (last-neg null))
    (if (null? lst)
        last-neg
        (let ((c (car lst)))
          (sub (cdr lst) (if (negative? c) c last-neg))))))
```

using a so-called "named let".

Comment: Your answer seems to be the shortest. But it's not as easy for me to understand.  Can you please walk me through it?  I'm kind of confused how last-neg gets originally set and why you have (sub lst null) defined at the bottom, and why you define two parameters for your lambda procedure inside sub, but then only pass one parameter (cdr list) when you call sub?